# Why is .NET `PixelFormat` has an `Format8bppIndexed` element?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, bitmap, pixel, grayscale

A group of 8 bits can store 256 values.

A gray level can have 256 variations.

So, why do they need `Format8bppIndexed`? Why is it `Indexed`?

Why not `Format8bpp` ?

Comment: Can you clarify why you think grayscale is relevant here? Sure, you *can* have 8 bit gray scale (although you can also have 16 bit gray scale, etc...) but that doesn't mean that's the *only* thing you can do with 8 bits per pixel.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70442/C-RGB-to-Palette-Based-bit-Greyscale-Bitmap-Clas

Comment: What about it? What are *you* trying to achieve? Note that although the palette used in that particular case only contains shades of grey, that doesn't mean it's always the case.

Comment: The notion of a indexed formats dates back to the early 1990s.  It was necessary back then because hardware still sucked, memory being the major constraint back then.  Rather too bad that sucky hardware from 25 years ago keeps dragging down programmers and SO questions.   Lets move on for crissake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's indexed because each value is an index into a colour table, which may well be RGB or RGBA with considerably more depth. For example, you could have a palette of 32-bit entries (8 bits for each of red, green, blue and alpha), but the palette itself only has 256 entries, so you can represent each pixel with a single byte. This is (or used to be, at least) common in PNG files.

If you look down the `PixelFormat` enumeration, you'll see that most values compose two pieces of information:

- Number of bits
- What those bits represent, out of:

  - Greyscale
  - ARGB / RGB
  - Indexed

Comment: can you please provide a diagram or any further resource?

Comment: @anonymous: Not really - it's a fairly simple concept. There's a palette (usually provided elsewhere in the image file) of colours, and each pixel value is an index into that palette. Which bit of it are you finding tricky?